# Aligning labels within a list element

Tags: html, css

I need to align the labels on the left hand side properly, so that the textbox and text area at the same place..I have added a class to set the width but that does not work properly.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WNr6D/1/)

Code:

```
<div id="feedbackdialogbox">
    <div>
        <h3>Feedback</h3>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="feedback_nm" class="feedback-label-len">(Optional) tell us who you are</label>
            <input type="text" id="feedback_name">
            <br>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="feedback_msg" class="feedback-label-len">How can we do better?</label>
            <textarea rows="5" id="feedback_msg" placeholder="Go ahead, type your feedback her..."></textarea>
            <br>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="radio_button_list_title_wrapper">
                <div id="radio_button_list_title" class="feedback-label-len">How likely are you to recommend Prices Paid to a colleague (1 means not likely, 5 means very likely)?</div>
            </div>
            <br>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button id="feedback_submit">Send</button>
</div>
```

css

```
.feedback-label-len {
    width:600px;
}
```

Comment: Just break the line and it will look better.

Comment: `display: block;` for `<label>`

Answer (score 0):

I think if I were in your place, I'd just add two `</br>` below the labels.

They are:

1. On the left hand side
2. They are left-aligned as well.

This obviously shall give you the same effect as

```
label {display:block;}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding display: block to the labels would be a fine solution for a simple form. If you're set on putting them side by side...

```
label {display: block; float: left}
li {overflow: hidden
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.feedback-label-len {
    display: block;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WNr6D/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a table.
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/EBv8s/)

```
<form method="post" action="feedback.php">
                            <table id="feedbackTable">
                              <tr>
                                <th><label for="txtName">(Optional) tell us who you are</label></th>
                                <td><input type="text" id="txtName" style="color:#000000" title="Enter your name" name="txtName" placeholder="Enter Your Name" /></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>  
                                <th class="message"><label for="">How can we do better?</label></th>
                                <td><textarea title="Enter your message" name="txtMessage" rows="5" id="txtMessage" placeholder="Go ahead, type your feedback her..."></textarea></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>  
                                <th><label for="txtEmail">How likely are you to recommend Prices Paid to a colleague (1 means not likely, 5 means very likely)?</label></th>
                                <td><input  type="text" id="txtEmail" title="Enter your email address" name="txtEmail" value=""/></td>
                              </tr>

                              <tr>
                                <th><label title="Send"></label></th>
                                <td><input type="submit" style="color:#000000" value="Send" /></td>
                              </tr>
                             </table>
                        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach you can try using is using tables in order to format the data. Using the table, tr (table row), and td (table data) html tags we can format the data in so that they are spaced correctly without using CSS!!!

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="feedbackdialogbox">
            <div>
                <h3>Feedback</h3>
            </div>
            <table>
                <ul>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <li><label for="feedback_nm" class="feedback-label-len">(Optional) tell us who you are</label></li></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="feedback_name"></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><li><label for="feedback_msg" class="feedback-label-len">How can we do better?</label></li></td>
                        <td><textarea rows="5" id="feedback_msg" placeholder="Go ahead, type your feedback her..."></textarea></td>

                    </li></tr>
                    <li>
                        <div id="radio_button_list_title_wrapper">
                            <div id="radio_button_list_title" class="feedback-label-len">How likely are you to recommend Prices Paid to a colleague (1 means not likely, 5 means very likely)?</div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </table>
            <button id="feedback_submit">Send</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Just so you know this method may upset html purists. The  tag was designed to actually display table data and using it for other purposes such as formatting is sometimes considered improper by old school web coders. However it I have not been able to find an actual problem caused by formatting data like this and doing so is the easiest way for you to make pages such as the one you are asking about.

I hope this answered your question, if you need me to expand on this just ask but when I ran the code above it gave me something much like you described.